# How to delete only float numbers in my string text

Tags: php

This is my variable, so i want that php removes all float numbers in my string and Print this result on the browser:

```
   <?php
   //1- this my variable
   $var = "100 1-testB/10000 20000.100 200 2-testB/2/20000 20000.200 300 3-testB/30000 30000.3000";
  //2- I want to delete only the float numbers in my string and get This Result: 
  //Result I want: 100 1-testB/10000 200 2-testB/2/20000 300 3-testB/30000 
  //3- i wrote this code for to do that:
   $output = trim(preg_replace("/\s*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b\s*/", " ", $var));
   echo $output; 
   //4- but the result is that: -testB/ -testB/ / -testB/  
   //#any help please?
   ?>
```

Comment: That does what you asked. If you want other things removed as well, the question is different

Comment: -RiggsFolly I'm sorry i thought that the old question was enough but it was not, any help please?

Comment: I am really bad at regex so I would tidy the result up using a `str_replace()` but thats just Mr Simple Me

Comment: I don't care about the way,i just want a solution, so any help please?

Comment: `$output = str_replace(['-','/'], ' ', $output);`

Comment: didn't work bro

Comment: Run after the regex right?

Comment: the regex destroy the result, so str_replace can't do anything

Comment: The preg... creates `$output` the str_replace runs on `$output`

Comment: whrite your answer as an complete answer not as a comment please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to get the job done:

```
$var = "100 1-testB/10000 20000.100 200 2-testB/2/20000 20000.200 300 3-testB/30000 30000.3000";
$output = explode(' ', $var);
foreach ($output as $k => $v) {
  if (FALSE !== strpos($v, '.')) {unset($output[$k]);}
}
$output = implode(' ', $output);
echo $output;  // 100 1-testB/10000 200 2-testB/2/20000 300 3-testB/30000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$var = "100 1-testB/10000 20000.100 200 2-testB/2/20000 20000.200 300 3-testB/30000 30000.3000";
$output = preg_replace("/\s*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b\s*/", " ", $var);
$output = trim(preg_replace('/[\s\-\/]+/mu', ' ', $output));
echo $output;
```

RESULT

```
testB testB testB
```